# Apple iPad trouble with window dimensions

Tags: ipad, safari

Am trying to juggle a pair of "then" and "now" JPEG images on an iPad running Safari. In my BODY declaration I catch onload and onresize and call JavaScript which looks at window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight. Problem is, Safari appears to report accurate information for landscape orientation of iPad but not for portrait. For landscape, Safari reports inner 981x644 and outer 1024x673. But for portrait, Safari reports inner 980x1185 and outer 768x929. My JavaScript looks at whether the orientation is landscape or portrait and then resizes the pair of JPEGs for side-by-side or top-and-bottom, respectively. But that doesn't work well when Safari is lying about the dimensions. Can anyone explain what is happening here? Thanks.

Comment: Additional point: Safari reports screen.width=768 and screen.height=1024 regardless of iPad orientation.

Comment: While this doesn't address your specific question, is there any specific reason you're using JavaScript to handle layout? It seems you would be better off using CSS media queries to handle this task?

Comment: If I can accomplish what I want, side-by-side for landscape, top-and-bottomm for portrait, resizing on the fly [the two images can have very different dimensions], I'm happy to learn. Can you vector me to some CSS media query examples? HTML TABLE is NG, because that's fixed format, either one row with two columns, or one column with two rows, but can't adjust dynamically for iPad orientation rotation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why it does so (it's driving me crazy as well)

But I can offer a solution to your problem: do it with CSS instead of JS!

You can do it using media queries to build a different layout for portrain and landscape:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) {
    ...
}
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
    ...
}
```

and using CSS3 to auto-size the images while keeping their aspect ratio:

```
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
```

Here is a JSFiddle with all the required code: http://jsfiddle.net/BULxm/

Hele is a direct link to the results, for testing on an iPad: http://fiddle.jshell.net/BULxm/show/